# If $A, B$ is a non-trivial partition of $S^1$, is it possible that $R_\theta(A) \cap B$ has measure zero for all rotations $R_\theta$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, rotations

As in the question title, let $A, B$ be a partition of the unit circle $S^1$, equipped with the Haar measure. Here, we *do not* require $A, B$ to be measurable. Also, assume neither $A$ nor $B$ is of measure zero, so they are either both non-measurable or both of positive measure. Is it possible, then, for $R_\theta(A) \cap B$ to be measurable and has Haar measure zero for all $\theta$, where $R_\theta$ is the rotation by degree $\theta$?

Comment: Sure, for example if $A$ is of measure $0$ to begin with.

Comment: Oh oh sorry, my bad, I forgot to exclude that case. I’ll edit the question.

Comment: If all rotations are around the origin, then if A is a disk and B is the inner circle the intersection is just a circle (measure 0) and both sets are rotation-invariant.

Comment: @Zanzag In the question I meant $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the *unit circle*, not the unit disk. It might be somewhat confusing to call the usual measure on the unit circle Lebesgue measure, I’ll edit the question to clarify I meant the Haar measure on $S^1$.

Comment: Since $S^1$ is the quotient space of $\mathbb R$ and rotations are basically translations, I think we can reformulate the question to this. Given a partition $\mathbb R=A\cup B$, where $A=\cup_{n\in \mathbb Z}(n+U)$ and $B=\cup_{n\in \mathbb Z}(n+V)$ and $U,V$ is a partition of $[0,1]$. Can we find such $U$ and $V$ of non-zero measure such that the measure of $(x+A)\cap B$ is zero for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @NewB Indeed that is equivalent. Though I'm not assuming $U$ and $V$ are of non-zero measure, they may be non-measurable at all. (Equivalently we could just say they are of non-zero *outer* measure.) I originally encountered the question not on $S^1$ but on $[0, 1]$ with rotation replaced by translation modulo 1. I reformulated it to be on the unit circle as I thought it would be easier to state this way. In retrospect your version might have been better.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447925/if-a-b-is-a-non-trivial-partition-of-s1-is-it-possible-that-r-thetaa